Partial trace on a two-mode continuous-variable quantum state
I have the following continuous-variable entangled state
$$ \left|\psi\right\rangle_{1,2}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq_{1} dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) f_{G}(q_{2})e^{\frac{i}{2} q_{1}q_{2}}\left|q_{1}\right\rangle \left|q_{2}\right\rangle, \tag{1}$$
where
$ f_{G}(q_{2})=\left(\frac{V_{s}^{2}}{2\pi} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-V_{s}^2 q_{2}^{2}/4}$ is a Gaussian function with a positive parameter $V_{s}^2 >0$. Besides, $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are position variables; therefore, the $\left\lbrace\left|q_{1}\right \rangle\right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace\left|q_{2}\right \rangle\right\rbrace$ are the position basis of systems 1 and 2 respectively. The quantum state of Eq. (1) represents a continuous-variable cluster, as can be verified from Weedbrook, Eq. (175).
Concretely, I need the position and momentum probability distributions of the reduced system 1 of Eq. (1). To compute the position probability distribution, I proceed as follows. First, I calculate the joint density operator associated with the state of Eq. (1); that is,
$$\hat{\rho}_{1,2}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq_{1}dq_{1}' dq_{2}dq_{2}'~\psi(q_{1})\psi^{\ast}(q_{1}') f_{G}(q_{2})f_{G}(q_{2}') e^{\frac{i}{2} q_{1}q_{2}}e^{-\frac{i}{2} q_{1}'q_{2}'}\left(\left|q_{1}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{1}'\right| \otimes \left|q_{2}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{2}'\right|\right), \tag{2}$$
where we have used $f_{G}^{\ast}(q_{2})=f_{G}(q_{2})$ since that function is real. Now, we obtain the reduced density operator of system 1 through the partial trace on system 2, for this, I use the basis $\left\lbrace \left|Q_{2}\right\rangle\right\rbrace$; then, I mean
$$\hat{\rho}_{1}=\text{Tr}\left[ \hat{\rho}_{1,2}\right] \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  dQ_{2}dq_{1}dq_{1}' dq_{2}dq_{2}'~\psi(q_{1})\psi^{\ast}(q_{1}') f_{G}(q_{2})f_{G}(q_{2}') e^{\frac{i}{2} q_{1}q_{2}}e^{-\frac{i}{2} q_{1}'q_{2}'}\left(\left|q_{1}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{1}'\right| \otimes \left\langle Q_{2}\right.\left|q_{2}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{2}'\right|\left. Q_{2}\right\rangle\right)\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  dQ_{2}dq_{1}dq_{1}' ~\psi(q_{1})\psi^{\ast}(q_{1}') \left[f_{G}(Q_{2}) \right]^2 e^{\frac{i}{2} Q_{2}(q_{1}-q_{1}')}\left|q_{1}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{1}'\right| \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq_{1}dq_{1}' ~\psi(q_{1})\psi^{\ast}(q_{1}') f_{G}(q_{1}-q_{1}')  e^{\frac{i}{2} Q_{2}(q_{1}-q_{1}')}\left|q_{1}\right\rangle \left\langle q_{1}'\right|, \tag{3}
$$
where in the second line of the last equation, we solve the integrals on $q_{2}$ and $q_{2}'$ by using the Dirac deltas:
$\delta(Q_{2}-q_{2})=\left\langle Q_{2}\right.\left|q_{2}\right\rangle $ and $\delta(q_{2}'-Q_{2})=\left\langle q_{2}'\right|\left. Q_{2}\right\rangle$; besides, in the third line we solve the integral on $Q_{2}$ by utilizing the definition of $f_{G}(Q_{2})$; that is,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dQ_{2}~\left[f_{G}(Q_{2}) \right]^2 e^{\frac{i}{2} Q_{2}(q_{1}-q_{1}')}=f_{G}(q_{1}-q_{1}')=e^{\frac{\left(q_{1}-q_{1}'\right)^2}{8V_{s}^2}}. \tag{4}$$
Then, the diagonal elements of $\hat{\rho}_{1}$ provide the position probability distribution $P(q_{1})$ of system 1; then, by utilizing a basis $\left\lbrace \left|Q_{1}\right\rangle\right\rbrace$, I take the diagonal elements of the reduced density operator $\hat{\rho}_{1}$ of Eq. (3); that is,
$$P(Q_{1})=\left\langle Q_{1}\right| \hat{\rho}_{1} \left|Q_{2} \right\rangle=\left| \psi(Q_{1})\right|^2, \tag{5}$$
where I have solved the integrals on $q_{1}$ and $q_{1}'$ by using the Dirac deltas: $\delta(Q_{1}-q_{1})=\left\langle Q_{1}\right.\left|q_{1}\right\rangle $ and $\delta(q_{1}'-Q_{1})=\left\langle q_{1}'\right|\left. Q_{1}\right\rangle$. Hence, Eq. (5) represents the position probability distribution associated with the reduced system 1 of the state of Eq. (1); therefore, my questions are:
How to obtain the momentum probability distribution associated with the reduced system 1 of Eq. (1)?
Can I take the Fourier transform of Eq. (5) in order to obtain the momentum probability distribution of the reduced system 1?

Did you check that (1) is normalized? The normalization would impose a condition on $\psi(q_1)$.

Based on (4), the last expression in (3) should not contain an exponential anymore. In (4) there is a bit of an abuse of notation because $f_G$ is not the same function inside the integral and in the result.

What is the formal process of "taking the diagonal elements"?

Given a state $\hat{\rho}$, the average position of the state is given by
$$ \langle x\rangle = \text{tr}\{\hat{\rho}\hat{X}\} , $$
where $\hat{X}$ is a position operator. In the current context with $|q\rangle$ representing a position basis, the position operator is given by
$$ \hat{X} = \int |q\rangle x \langle q|\ dq , $$
so that $\hat{X}|q\rangle=|q\rangle x$.
When we now compute the average position of your final state, we get
$$ \langle x\rangle = \text{tr}\{\hat{\rho}_1\hat{X}\} 
= \int |\psi(q)|^2 q\ dq . $$
So one can interpret the diagonal as the probability distribution for position.
In a similar way, the momentum operator is defined by
$$ \hat{P} = \int |p\rangle p \langle p|\ dp , $$
where
$$ \langle q|p\rangle = \exp(iqp) . $$
The average momentum is now given by
$$ \langle p\rangle = \text{tr}\{\hat{\rho}_1\hat{P}\} 
= \int p\exp[-ip(q_1-q_1')]\psi(q_1)\psi(q_1')\tilde{f}_G(q_1-q_1')\ dq_1 dq_2 dp , $$
where I changed the OP notation so that $\tilde{f}_G$ is the function obtained in (4). The momentum distribution is now given by the part of the integrant of the integral over $p$ without the factor of $p$.
